# Asyntask #1 Android error

Tags: java, android, mysql, google-maps

**NEW VERSION 1.1**

Hi guys. I tried to follow your recommendations and now i'm trying to redo the code.
I added this part of the code to work on the Main Thread the GoogleMaps markers.

The problem is, when i call the Ubic() function, i get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkudh.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUTcF.jpg

This is the code that i added an the error is caused by String Latlon[][] = com.Ubic();

```
public class BuscarContrincantes extends FragmentActivity implements
    LocationListener {

GoogleMap googlemapa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscarcontrincante);

    SupportMapFragment maps = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    googlemapa = maps.getMap();
    googlemapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

    double latitud;
    double longitud;
    String nombre;

    Datos com = new Datos();

    String latlon[][] = com.Ubic(); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!

    for (int i = 0; i < latlon.length - 1; i++) {
        latitud = Double.parseDouble(latlon[i][0]);
        longitud = Double.parseDouble(latlon[i][3]);
        nombre = (latlon[i][2]);

        LatLng posicion = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);

        googlemapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.icono_canchas))
                .position(posicion).title(nombre));


}

}
```

---

**VERSION 1.0**

I'm having a problem with a project that i'm doing for my college.

Actually, i'm trying to set a Marker on a Map (With Google Maps) that his information is on a MySQL Database.

The code is:

BuscarContrincantes.java

```
public class BuscarContrincantes extends FragmentActivity implements
    LocationListener {

GoogleMap googlemapa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscarcontrincante);

    SupportMapFragment maps = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    googlemapa = maps.getMap();
    googlemapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

    new RetreiveFeedTask().execute();

}

class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        double lat;
        double lon;
        String nombre;

        Datos com = new Datos(); // File Datos.java
        String latlon[][] = com.Ubic();

        for (int i = 0; i < latlon.length - 1; i++) {
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latlon[i][0]);
            lon = Double.parseDouble(latlon[i][4]);
            nombre = (latlon[i][2]);

            LatLng pos3 = new LatLng(lat, lon);

            googlemapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.icono_canchas))
                    .position(pos3).title(nombre));

        }
        return null;

    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Datos.java

```
public class Datos {
public String[][] Ubic() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "http://MY.IP/FOLDER/QUERY.php");

    try {

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);


        JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("products");
        String[] lat = new String[arr.length()+1];
        String[] lon = new String[arr.length()+1];
        String[] nombre = new String[arr.length() + 1];

        String[][] latlon = new String[arr.length() + 1][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            lat[i] = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude");
            lon[i] = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude");
            name[i] = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            latlon[i][0] = lat[i];
            latlon[i][6] = lon[i];
            latlon[i][2] = name[i];
        }
        return latlon;

    } catch (JSONException e) {

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return null;

}

private static String parse(String string) {
    return null;

}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String rLine = "";
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            answer.append(rLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return answer;
}}
```

This code is trying to get Latitude, Longitude and Name of an object that is on a MySQL Database and must put this object on the Map, but i'm getting the AsynkTask #1 Error and i don't know why this is happening.
¿Can you help me, please? I'm getting really mad with this code and i don't know why this isn't working.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English. I'm from Chile :P

Comment: Post the logcat from the crash

Comment: Now i added the SS from the crash :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the GoogleMap instance at `doInBackground` method. The GoogleMap can only be read and modified from the main thread. Just the HTTP request shall be on background task.

You need to modify `doInBackground` to return the list of coordinates and implement the GoogleMap update at `onPostExecute` method (at main thread).

Here is the code based on Version 1.1:

```
GoogleMap googlemapa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscarcontrincante);

    SupportMapFragment maps = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    googlemapa = maps.getMap();
    googlemapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googlemapa.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

    new RetreiveFeedTask().execute();
}

class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[][]> {

    @Override
    protected String[][] doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // Execute the HTTP request on background task
        Datos com = new Datos(); // File Datos.java
        return com.Ubic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[][] latlon) {
        double latitud;
        double longitud;
        String nombre;

        // Update the UI
        for (int i = 0; i < latlon.length - 1; i++) {
            latitud = Double.parseDouble(latlon[i][0]);
            longitud = Double.parseDouble(latlon[i][3]);
            nombre = (latlon[i][2]);

            LatLng posicion = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);

            googlemapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icono_canchas)).position(posicion).title(nombre));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Now i'm having a new error, but i think that you could help me with this.